# facebook messenger api context

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

I am playing with facebook messenger API

I wonder if there is a way to maintain context of the conversation. Maybe some kind of sequence order, or payload after messages.

Thank you.

Comment: You get the user ID of the user that you are talking with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages include a `mid` you can use:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/message